# static structure array openmp parallel for

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp, parallel.for

I have C code structured like below:

```
typedef struct
{
    double diam;
    double more_values;
    other_struct other_structures;
    ...
}ant_struct;
```

and a static declaration below:

```
static ant_struct ant[MAX_NUM_ANTENNAS];
```

I have another section of the code that is part of an non-linear optimization of antenna performance.  In that section a logical loop looks like below:

```
initialize_all_antennas();

for (int i = 0; i < num_vertices; i++)
{
    // set antenna parameters on the static structure array to bounded values 
        randomize_antenna();

    // Compute antenna performance by evaluating a cost function that has access to the antenna static information using a lot of ant__get_value() functions.
        computed_cost = compute_cost();

    // Set the cost function cost for each vertex
        vertex[i].cost = computed_cost;
}
```

I am trying to parallelize the above using and have learned how to do this in other scenarios.

```
#pragma omp parallel for
```

I have found that you can make static variables threaded using

```
static __thread this_var
```

However, I am not sure that I am able to do this with ant because it is an array and I seem to be losing the initialization of the values that are not randomized in the randomize_antenna() function within the antenna structure.  I want to have each thread have its own local copy of the static ant array to set and retrieve values.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: It strikes me that using C's intrinsic capabilities for thread static variables (or whatever the heck their proper name is) in an OpenMP program is just going to lead to a world of pain.  Why aren't you using OpenMP's `shared` and `private` variable scoping to provide thread local data elements and arrays ?

Comment: The current code architecture essentially uses a set of global structures and in a sequential manner updates those structures (e.g. ant (antenna), rx (receiver), etc).  The logic is highly parallelizable but unfortunately the architecture seems to not be.  I am looking for any help I can get to utilize existing tools to speed the optimization up without restructuring the entire architecture.  One possibility is that this architecture does not well support parallelization.  If that's true, any insight is appreciated.